# Stored Procedure with conditional results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure that works something like this:

```
SELECT * from T where T.A = @a and T.B = @b
```

if that returns rows, return those rows, if not, return

```
SELECT * from T where T.A = @a and T.B IS NULL
```

**Edit:**

It feels that there should be a way to create a procedure such that it runs the first query **once** and runs the second query **only if necessary**.

End Edit.

The best I could manage was the follow, which (in theory) runs the first query twice, unless maybe its cached:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * from T where T.A = @a and T.B = @b) THEN
    SELECT * from T where T.A = @a and T.B = @b
ELSE
    SELECT * from T where T.A = @a and T.B IS NULL
```

For what its worth, this is in Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: And your question or problem is?!?!?!? You seem to have an approach - does it not work, or what's the issue?

Comment: If that's SQL Server 2000 then that's the best approach I know of but +1 cos I'd love to know if there is another way!

Comment: I believe he is asking if there is a more efficient way to do this. There is.

Comment: In SQL 2005 and up you could probably do some goofy things with CTEs to make it look like one query, but it'll probably end up reading and processing the same amount of data as the IF EXISTS... THEN... ELSE versions.

Comment: @Phillip - I just tried that but couldn't do `AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Results)` in the 2nd level as I got the error `Recursive references are not allowed in subqueries.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should avoid the additional table access for the existence check. I'm not sure if there's a neater way.

```
SELECT * from T where T.A = @a and T.B = @b


IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT * from T where T.A = @a and T.B IS NULL
END
```

Comment: I think this is the best performer, but your application has to look at the second result if the first result is empty.

Comment: I wasn't able to use this because of the multiple results sets, but this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with a table variable, which should avoid the two resultsets issue. Something like:

```
declare @result1 table ( ... )
insert into @result1 select * from T where T.A = @a and T.B = @b

if (@@rowcount = 0)
   select * from T where T.A = @a and T.B is null
else
   select * from @result1
```

Comment: There is an overhead with this approach though in creating the table variable, inserting to it, and then selecting from it that may outweigh any potential benefit of avoiding the check. I'm beginning to think the approach in the question can't really be bettered.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do this in a single query:

```
Select ...
From T
Where T.A = @a
    And T.B = @b
Union All
Select ...
From T
Where T.A = @a
    And T.B Is Null
    And Not Exists  (
                    Select 1
                    From T
                    Where T.A = @a
                        And T.B = @b
                    )
```

Another single query solution:

```
Select ...
From T
Where T.A = @a
    And T.B = @b
Union All
(Select ...
From T
Where T.A = @a
    And T.B Is Null
Except
Select ...
From T
Where T.A = @a
    And T.B = @b)
```

Comment: Single query yes, but same or worse execution plan.

Comment: @BC - Not necessarily. It might handle the parameter sniffing problem better than with the IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in one query:

```
SELECT * from T where (T.A = @a and T.B = @b) OR
( 0=(SELECT COUNT(*) T1 where (T1.A = @a and T1.B = @b) ) 
  AND T.A = @a and T.b IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it if helps at all performance-wise, but you could try table-valued function:

```
create function fun(@a <aType>, @b <bType>)
 returns @result (<...columns...>)
as begin
 insert into @result
 select * from T where T.A = @a and T.B = @b;

 if  (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) begin
  insert into @result
  select * from T where T.A = @a and T.B is null;
 end;
 return;
end;
GO
```

But I doubt it helps.

Generally I would stick with your original approach. It is the simplest and cleanest. And cache and good index should take care of performance.

If there were real performance problems here, I would step back and look at this database design. Why are you having nulls there? Why are you trying two filters? Can it be modeled differently? If not, maybe a little denormalization?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if the first select return rows , then it returns if the first fails then the next select returns or finally the last select:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Customers 

     INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID where Customers.CustomerID='BERJGS')
    BEGIN
             SELECT * FROM Customers 
                    INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID where Customers.CustomerID='BERJGS'
              PRINT 'TOLA'
              RETURN
     END
ELSE
     BEGIN
               SELECT * FROM Customers 
                    INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID where Customers.CustomerID='6CHOPS'             
              IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0             
                    RETURN              
              --RETURN
     END



SELECT * FROM Customers  where Customers.CustomerID='FRANK'
```

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT** The answer was edited after the question was edited.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myconditionalsp
@a  <type>,
@b  <type>
AS

SELECT * from T 
where 
    -- the second condition is true AND the first condition is false
    (((T.A = @a) and (T.B IS NULL)) AND NOT ((T.A = @a) and (T.B = @b)))
    OR 
    -- the first condition is true (regardless what is the second condition)
    ((T.A = @a) and (T.B = @b))
GO
```

Comment: For this to work the same way, the "AND NOT" part would need to be "AND NOT EXISTS (......)